# Hyperlink in GridView with one column

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have one column in my Gridview which has a `TemplateField` with URL in it. Now my question is in the `Text="Details"` instead of `Details` I want the `P_D_Name` in it.

This is my code:

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
     <Columns>
         <asp:BoundField DataField="P_D_Name" HeaderText="P_D_Name" 
                SortExpression="P_D_Name" Visible="False" />
         <asp:TemplateField>
             <ItemTemplate>
                 <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" Text="Details" Target="_blank" NavigateUrl='<%# "MYURL" + Eval("P_D_Name")%>'></asp:HyperLink>
             </ItemTemplate>
         </asp:TemplateField>
     </Columns>
 </asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just use the same type of DataBinding as you're using for the NavigateUrl:

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
     <Columns>
         <asp:BoundField DataField="P_D_Name" HeaderText="P_D_Name" 
                SortExpression="P_D_Name" Visible="False" />
         <asp:TemplateField>
             <ItemTemplate>
                 <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("P_D_Name")%>' Target="_blank" NavigateUrl='<%# "MYURL" + Eval("P_D_Name")%>'></asp:HyperLink>
             </ItemTemplate>
         </asp:TemplateField>
     </Columns>
 </asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace text with eval expression as follows:

Text="<%# Bind("P_D_Name") %>"

Answer (score 1):

```
//you just use "<%#Eval("P_D_Name") %>"    

<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" Text="<%#Eval("P_D_Name") %>" Target="_blank" NavigateUrl='<%# "MYURL" + Eval("P_D_Name")%>'></asp:HyperLink>
```